# ArcMap and xCode

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, swift

I have an ArcMap (.mxd file) With multiple layers and have different information mapped around my city. I was wondering if its possible to import this map into Swift code (xCode) and have different buttons on the screen that toggle layers?

I have seen how you can input ArcMap basemaps, however I am wondering about this custom map.

Answer (score 1):

I am uncertain about Xcode support of Shapefiles. You could try QGIS on MacOS X.
Also Esri has created ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS. It will display ArcGIS online maps and you can Use your map data offline. For more details look at https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/10-2/objective-c/guide/introduction.htm